# Edit kml polygons pop-up to open it all when click on one of that using Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth, polygon-creation

I have a couple of polygons in kml format and I want to open it in Google Earth. That what I need is when I click on one polygon than all other polygon pop-ups of same owner (or any unique field for all of these polygons) will automatically appear at the same time.
There must be some kml editing so I need someone familiar with this.

Comment: What does your KML snippet related to this look like so far?

Comment: Is that possible to do using Google maps if Google earth don't allow this? Also, is there any way to adjust kml file for this needs?

Answer (score 1):

In Google Earth (Pro / desktop) it is only possible to pop one balloon (info-window) at a time. Popping another will close any currently open one.

In the new Google Earth (on web & mobile), it is possible to have two balloons open at once, depending on what type of balloon they are. For example you can have one normal/default type balloon and one panel type balloon open on the map at the same time.

Multiple info-windows IS possible when using the Google Maps API. In your javascript, you can generate multiple InfoWindow objects, and they will be able to appear on the map at the same time.  More info here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows